# Apache Beam: Handling of late data

Tags: apache-beam

I am using fixed windows in my pipeline with this configuration

```
Window.<KV<String, DeviceData>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getWindowSize())))
                    .triggering(
                            AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                    .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(10))))
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(3))
                    .accumulatingFiredPanes();
```

Is my assumption correct that there will be one trigger after closing of the window and then additionally a trigger each 10 minutes after the window has closed if there is late data until 3 hours passed since the closing of the window?

How can I handle data import for periods in time that are further in past? (for example months). In this case I would receive no triggers at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are missing [Repeatedly.forever](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Repeatedly.html) to allow triggering multiple times, in order for it to match your description.

For data further in the past, you need to configure `.withAllowedLateness()` based on the lateness that you want to handle.

Comment: If i add Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()); - will it fire each time there is late data or will it continue to fire even there is no late data present?